# Get the full error in Nextjs 14 server components

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am using a server component in Nextjs to fetch data from Firestore.
This is the fetch call

```
async function getData() {
  let res;

  try {
    res = await dbAdmin
      .collectionGroup("Business")
      .where("info.slug.short", "==", "enterprise")
      .get();
  } catch (error) {
    // console.error(error);
    throw new Error(error);
  }

  if (!res.exists) {
    // This will activate the closest `error.js` Error Boundary
    // throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    return undefined;
  }

  return res.data();
}
```

I get error "Failed Precondition" which is a common Firestore error to say create an index for the query. The normal way is the error has a 'url' from firebase to go create the index.

Only the Error constructor somehow hides this details and am trying to retrieve the url from the error but is nowhere to be found.

How can I get the full error with nextjs.

The given "Failed Precondition" error only is very vague now and in future and even for beginners who are not familiar with Firestore errors

Comment: have you tryed `console.log(JSON.stringfy(error))` or returning a stringfyed version of the error?

Comment: Yes there is nothing in the url containing the full error details

Comment: The [Error constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Error) isn't designed to take another Error object as a parameter.  It takes a string message. Maybe you should just `throw error` if you want to propagate it. Or even just don't try to catch it at all and let `await` do that autmatically for you.

Comment: It is a NextJs 13, 14 thing https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling#handling-server-errors , the error is somehow cleaned and returned back. See also an example at https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/error-handling#handling-server-errors.