Firestore query error: Error 9 Failed precondition
I have trouble getting this Firebase Function to work, except in Firebase Emulator.
Here's the error message. It doesn't mention anything about indexes, but I still suspect that incorrect index is to blame.
"Unhandled error Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: 
    at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:357:73)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:94:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeServerStreamRequest (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:340:32)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/make-client.js:105:19)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:227:29
    at /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/streamingCalls/streamingApiCaller.js:38:28
    at /workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/normalCalls/timeout.js:44:16
    at Object.request (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/streamingCalls/streaming.js:130:40)
    at makeRequest (/workspace/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:141:28)
    at retryRequest (/workspace/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:109:5)
    at StreamProxy.setStream (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/streamingCalls/streaming.js:121:37)
    at StreamingApiCaller.call (/workspace/node_modules/google-gax/build/src/streamingCalls/streamingApiCaller.js:54:16)
Caused by: Error
    at Query._get (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1738:23)
    at Query.get (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1726:21)
    at /workspace/timesheet/management.js:219:28
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/onInit.js:33:16
    at fixedLen (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v1/providers/https.js:77:47)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:458:32
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  code: 9,
  details: '',
  metadata: Metadata {
    internalRepr: Map(1) { 'x-debug-tracking-id' => [Array] },
    options: {}
  }
}"

Here is the function in question. I put comments in parts where I've made troubleshooting attempts.
const filterTimesheetWorklogs = (worklogs, uid) => {
  return worklogs.filter(worklog => worklog.project.timesheetApprovers.includes(uid))
}

const isSpawnAllApproved = async (virtualTimesheetId, uid) => {
  // All timesheets with the same virtualTimesheetId with uid as one of the approvers are approved
  const collectionGroup = admin.firestore().collectionGroup("timesheets")
  const query = collectionGroup
    .where("virtualTimesheetId", "==", virtualTimesheetId)

  const snap = await query.get()

  const authorizedDocs = snap.docs.filter(async doc => {
    // const projectRef = doc.ref.parent.parent
    // const projectSnap = await projectRef.get()
    // const projectData = projectSnap.data()

    const { projectId } = doc.data()
    const projectCollectionGroup = admin.firestore().collectionGroup("projects")
    const projectQuery = projectCollectionGroup.where("timesheetApprovers", "array-contains", uid)
    const projectSnap = await projectQuery.get()
    const projectData = projectSnap.docs
      .map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }))
      .find(project => project.id === projectId)
    
    return projectData.timesheetApprovers.includes(uid)
  })

  return authorizedDocs.every(doc => {
    const data = doc.data()
    return data.status === "approved"
  })
}

const getAuthorizedVirtualTimesheets = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const { filter: { start, end }, companyId } = data;
  const { uid, token: { roles = {} } } = context.auth

  if ([
    Object.keys(roles).includes(companyId),
    roles[companyId].includes("timesheet approver") || roles[companyId].includes("admin"),
  ].some(v => !v)) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("permission-denied", "Unauthorized access.");
  }

  const collectionGroup = admin.firestore().collectionGroup("virtualTimesheets")
  const query = collectionGroup
    // I've tried removing these two `.where`'s, error persists
    .where("createdAt", ">=", dayjs(start).startOf("day").toDate())
    .where("createdAt", "<=", dayjs(end).endOf("day").toDate())
  
  const snap = await query.get()

  // I've tried removing this entire statement and just return
  const docs = await Promise.all(snap.docs
    .map(async doc => ({
      id: doc.id,
      ...doc.data(),
      worklogs: filterTimesheetWorklogs(doc.data().worklogs, uid),
      status: (await isSpawnAllApproved(doc.id, uid)) ? "approved" : null,
    })))
  return docs
})

Other troubleshooting attempts:

Created a composite index as described below (doesn't work):

Collection ID: virtualTimesheets
Fields:

createdAt ASC
createdAt DESC


Scope: Collection group


Removing both the where clauses and the Promise.all statement (the error disappears).


I suggest first eliminating Cloud Functions entirely and just run the query in a local nodejs program. This will help you to better debug and observe the issue.  The error call stack suggests this is a Firestore issue and not a Cloud Functions issue, but you are certainly complicating things by testing a Cloud Functions environment.

I'll also point out that you have potentially many different Firestore queries involved here, but it appears you haven't done anything to narrow down which specific query is causing the problem.  Please do that first, and shown the [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clearly illustrates which specific query fail.

UPDATE Looks like Google Cloud Console logs now displays the index creation URL along with the rest of the error info.

For me it was a missing index. I followed this example, where you can build your query on the firestore's query builder.
Step-1 To know which query is causing the issue look for queries around the Stack mentioned after "Caused By: Error" like in the above asked question.
It seems to be at or around --> at /workspace/timesheet/management.js:219:28.
Step-2 Run the exact query on the Query Builder on firestore.
Step-3 You will get an Error mentioning that you need to create an Index. Create that index and you are done.
https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/issues/1866#issuecomment-1793570113

I'm accepting this answer instead of my own because it does not involve compromising the security rules. I forgot that you can use Firestore's Query Builder.

Short answer
Replicate the queries you're trying to do in Firestore client SDK, deploy to Firebase, execute those queries and check the logs for what indexes those queries lack, build those indexes, and try again.
Long answer
My suspicion is correct: If there's a Firestore query in a Function that lacks an index, the error message will not give you the link to autogenerate. It won't even tell you that it's index-related.
So, I have to adjust some security rules, recreate the query in Firebase JavaScript SDK. Observe the errors and click the links. And then clean everything up and revert the security rules.
In my case here's how I replicate the query:
const collectionGroupRef = collectionGroup(myFirestoreInstance, "virtualTimesheets")
const q = query(
  collectionGroup,
  where("createdAt", ">=", startDate),
  where("createdAt", "<=", endDate),
)
const querySnapshot = getDocs(q)


Oh my this is the only solution. How is this the only solution? what changed in the admin sdk that this error could be seen but now the url to create the index is not in the error. I have spent so much time debugging this. The solution is tedious especially with multiple environments. The firebase team should fix this

I literally had a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77680486/get-the-full-error-in-nextjs-14-server-components. where the admin sdk does not give the url to create an index like the client sdk has.
