Where query on firestore
I have a collection of users, each with a collection called "logs". I have a collectionGroup with all "logs" collections. Each "logs" collection have documents which are named with automated IDs. Each document has a date field. I am trying to perform a where query to only get the logs from today but it is not working. I keep getting Error: 9 FAILED_PRECONDITION: \n    at callErrorFromStatus.
The code looks like this
const collectionGroup = db
        .collectionGroup("logs")
        .where("date", ">=", Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(todayStart.toISO())))
        .where("date", "<=", Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(todayEnd.toISO())));

const logDocumentsSnapshot = await collectionGroup.get();

The hierarchy of the database is
users (collection)
--A0Ugoso03BcEvBRljMNs (document containing an user with these automated IDs)
----logs (collection)
------KkuZurnbvcEnYPRUe3kw (document containing logs with these automated IDs. That's the document that contains the date field)
Does anyone know how to make a successful where query and only get back the logs that are within today?

This usually means you're missing an index that the query needs. I recommend reading up on indexes here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/index-overview (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78545358/firebase-functions-error-9-failed-precondition)
